# What is a Non-Expansion?

Tags: notation

I was reading [this article from arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05628.pdf) and I got confused on the first page, when it says, "a non-expansion for all parameter settings ensuring
convergence to a unique fixed point." What is a non-expansion? What does the excerpt mean?

Comment: ftp://ftp.cs.brown.edu/pub/techreports/96/cs96-10.pdf

See page 6.